# Mysql (doctrine) is duplicating count results probably due to grouping by but can't figure it out

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, left-join

I'm using doctrine as an ORM layer but by putting a plain mysql query in my database tool i got the same results. So my problem:

I have an invoices table, invoice_items and invoice_payments table and what i would like to get as an result is all invoices that are not paid or at least not fully paid yet. I know that the query should be almost correctly because its giving the correct amount of items back... the only thing is that it is multiplying the amount by a number of probably joined rows.

So the query that i have for now:

```
select  invoice.*, sum(item.amount * item.quantity) as totalDue, 
        sum(payment.amount) as totalPaid 
from invoices as invoice 
    left join invoice_items as item on item.invoice_id = invoice.id 
    left join invoice_payments as payment on payment.invoice_id = invoice.id 
        and payment.status = 'successful' 
where invoice.invoice_number is not null 
and invoice.sent_at is not null 
and invoice.due_date >= '2018-05-15' 
group by invoice.id 
having count(payment.id) = 0 
    or sum(payment.amount) < sum(item.amount * item.quantity) 
order by invoice.issue_date desc, sum(payment.amount) desc;
```

As you can see i also have totalDue and totalPaid in my select (those are for reference only and should be removed if the query is correct).

What i saw is that the amount is multiplied by six (because it has 6 items in the payments table).

So maybe someone could help me pointing in the right direction that it doesn't do the multiplying on the totalDue. I was thinking its probably because the group by but without my query is failing.

Comment: For future reference, if we can read your code there is more likelyhood that someone WILL actually stop and read it

Comment: `(sum(payment.amount) < sum(item.amount * item.quantity))` Set with `()` for making difference.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i tried but didn't work directly thought that the editor should help me by pretty print it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting OR simply look at what I did to format your query so it is all viewable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply using a distinct in my query i fixed the problem.

```
select invoice.*, sum(distinct(item.amount * item.quantity)) as totalDue, 
        sum(payment.amount) as totalPaid 
from invoices as invoice 
    left join invoice_items as item on item.invoice_id = invoice.id 
    left join invoice_payments as payment on payment.invoice_id = invoice.id 
        and payment.status = 'successful' 
where invoice.invoice_number is not null 
and invoice.sent_at is not null 
and invoice.due_date >= '2018-05-15' 
group by invoice.id 
having count(payment.id) = 0 
    or sum(payment.amount) < sum(distinct(item.amount * item.quantity)) 
order by invoice.issue_date desc, sum(payment.amount) desc;
```

I would like to thank all the people who had taken the time to re-style my question ;-)